# How can I read spaces in a Python string, store their exact positions, and then reinsert them in a new string at those positions?

Tags: python, cryptography, caesar-cipher

I am writing a caesar cipher program and am successfully encrypting my strings but am losing the spaces in the process. I'd like to be able to read the spaces in the original plaintext string and then have them be reinserted in the new string.

I am aware of the replace method but I feel it restricts freedom on the user's end in terms of selecting what key to use (replace method being static).

Comment: Or you can add space to your cipher vocabulary and encrypt it as well. This will make process of decryption a little harder.

Comment: Why not just modify your program to not remove the spaces in the first place?

Comment: Could you please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem? It is difficult to debug code that we are not given.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it works:

```
a=[]
for i in range(len(string)):
   if string(i)==" ":
      a.append(i)
```

Now you have stored the locations,if you want to insert them at their exact positions in the new text try this:

```
b=list(newstring)
for i in a:
   b[i]=" "
```

This will add a space to the positions in the string in the first part,now turn it to string again:

```
c=""
for i in b:
   c=c+i
```